# Azure AD + Open ID -> Restricting signin domain

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I'm trying to configure Open Id Connect for an internal business application based on asp.net core.

Due to internal directory versioning, I can't connect directly to an ADFS server (not running ADFS 2016, so Open Id Connect isn't available). There is a directory sync with Azure AD, and so will authenticate via Azure AD.

I've got it working, however as the users of the application will only ever be from a given domain I'm wanting to automate past the email prompt.

[image: login email prompt]

The current flow is, hit Azure AD -> enter company domain -> kicked through to internal ADFS server -> (domain connected machine) AD automatic signin -> Azure AD -> Application.

Because all users of this application will all be from the same domain, and end up going via the ADFS server anyway I want to skip the email prompt (to just determine the IDP for the domain) so the whole experience is seamless.

Is there a setting, or flag that can be used to tell Azure AD to automatically infer the company domain? (i.e. contoso.onmicrosoft.com). I've based my solution off the following Microsoft sample:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore

Which has a "Domain" configuration value, but it is not used anywhere in the code.

Comment: Do you want to resitrict one domain user sign in ?

Comment: Yes, all users will be from a single domain and so I want them to automatically be forwarded through to the IDP for that domain.

Comment: Hi,@Technicolour. Have you tried use `domain_hint` to specify one domain? With domain_hint, you can skip the Home Realm Discovery Page.But this also let all the user in that tenant can login your app.It usually used for Multi-tenant App.

Comment: How can that be configured in asp.net core?

Comment: This blog may be helpful:http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/

Comment: If you want to restrict users to sign in your App. I suggest you can use group to clarify one domain users and assign app role to them and  enable User assign required in the serviceprincipal.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT domain_hint was exactly what I was looking for. I just missed the keywords of home realm discovery. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wayne Yang highlighted. Needed to add in the `domain_hint` parameter.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = azureAdOptions.ClientId;
            options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azureAdOptions.TenantId}";
            options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += (RedirectContext context) =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = azureAdOptions.Domain;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        })
        .AddCookie();
```

Comment: Right, the domain hint tells Azure AD that users are probably gonna sign in with `company.com` domains. In this case since AAD sees that `company.com` is a domain federated from on-prem AD using AAD Connect, it redirects to the ADFS automatically, skipping the AAD login screen and home realm discovery.

Comment: Yup exactly. Neat way to get around older versions of ADFS not supporting newer protocols